# How to end VBScript on Windows 10?

Tags: task-manager, vbscript

I accidently did a cd-drive vbs prank on myself on windows 10 and I can't find the wscript.exe file.. Is there any way to end this program?

Comment: rebooting windows? from task manager?

Comment: @MátéJuhász There is no process visible in task manager

Comment: Reboot?  Look for `cscript.exe` processes instead of `wscript.exe` (it's the other scripting host process).

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 There are no files like that there, any other way?

Comment: VBS needs a scripting host to run; wscript and csscript are the Windows scripting host processes that run VBS scripts. If a VBS script is running, one of those MUST be running.  Where exactly are you looking for them in the Task Manager?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I'm looking in the background processes and there is no process like scripting or any like wscript or csscript.

Comment: Just reboot. Unless you have set it to run at start. In which case, disable that then reboot.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your script probably runs elevated so could become invisible in *normal* unelevated task manager. Run it elevated as well.

Another approach: open an **elevated** command line window. Then, `taskkill /?` could suggest a solution (or read [`taskkill`: End one or more processes by process ID or image name](http://ss64.com/nt/taskkill.html) article).

To find *process ID* of **any** running  [Windows scripting engine i.e either `wscript.exe` or `cscript.exe`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/245254), type

```
tasklist | findstr /I "PID script.exe"
```

and search for `.vbs` i.e. VBScript file extension:

```
wmic process where "CommandLine like '%.vbs%' and name != 'wmic.exe'" get /value
```

and search for your script file name (let's say `cdprank.vbs`):

```
wmic process where "CommandLine like '%cdprank%' and name != 'wmic.exe'" get /value
```

Answer (score 12):

Best option according to me is

1) Open Task Manager

2) Go to the processes tab

3) Right-click on Name header and click command line (to show Command line)

4) Under command line look for "C:\Windows\System32\WScript.exe" "yourfilename.vbs"

5) Right-click and end task

Comment: Brilliant stuff. This works like a charm on window 10. Thanks a ton for sharing.

Comment: Much easier, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Look for something called "Microsoft Windows Based Script Host" in the running processes. End this process and you should be fine.

Comment: How does this differ from the accepted answer

Comment: This is how I do it as well.  Why was this down-voted?  Much simpler than the accepted answer.  You just run Task Manager, look for the above string, and click "end task".

Answer (score 0):

For Windows 10 TaskManager>Details search for wscript.exe Right click and select End Process tree.

Comment: That helped. Thanx.

Answer (score 0):

Look for a process called "microsoft windows based script host" in task manager on the process tab. End task the process and your done

Comment: How is this better than other answers?